# Long times on get pooled connection from datasource

Tags: database, jdbc, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Lately we have  been having a lot of lag with getting pooled connections from datasource. Is this a db issue ? Would slow DB be a cause of this or should we check application code for a fix for this. This happens intermittently though. Would increasing pool size work or is there any other fix or checks.
Thanks

```
<service interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
       <service-properties>
          <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/Idn/pfile/DataSource" />
      </service-properties>
      <bean class="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource">
          <property name="serverName" value="${host}" />
          <property name="portNumber" value="${port}" />
          <property name="databaseName" value="${dbName}" />
          <property name="currentSchema" value="${schema}" />
          <property name="user" value="${user}" />
          <property name="password" value="${password}" />
          <property name="driverType" value="${drivertype}" />
          <property name="dataSourceName" value="${dataSource.name}" />
      </bean>
 </service>
```

Comment: are you using a camel component to interact with your database?  if so, include the setup and details about your use scenario...

Comment: have added to question

Answer (score 0):

try using the DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource or other JDBC connection pool (DBCP, etc)